# Domino HTTP Server: Error - Unable to Bind 1.2.3.4, port 80, port in use or Bind To Host configuration specifies a duplicate IP address/host

Tags: ibm-domino

We have a Domino 9.0.1 Server hosted on Ubuntu 14.04 Server, which hosts several other http based Tasks, (Nginx, Couchdb, Confluence on Tomcat).

The Ubuntu Server has multiple IPs, all bind correctly to the different Tasks.

The Domino SMTP task binds correctly and is working well.

All http tasks (other than Domino) are proxied behind Nginx version 1.6x and all are working well, netstat shows no 0.0.0.0 bindings, no one is listening on 1.2.3.4:80 .

when I try to `load http` on the (Domino) server console it failes with

```
HTTP Server: Error - Unable to Bind 1.2.3.4, port 80, port in use or Bind To Host configuration specifies a duplicate IP address/host
```

a couple of times, may be 4 or 5 times then it loads without failure!

And: when it comes up, I see http is listening on 80 AND 443, but SSL Connections are not working, nor any error log!

It must be a kind of bad magic :-(

thanks in advance

Pitt

Answer (score 0):

Is Domino running as root? Only root can bind to port 80.

What is the output of `ss -lt`?

Are multiple bind ip:ports specified in the http config database as the error suggests?